Client freezes on recv despite server confirming data receipt (seems to only work on my machine)
I’m trying to create a simple client-server program in C. The server receives a message from the client and sends back a response. Here are the code snippets:
client.c:
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == -1) {
        perror("Could not create socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(8080);

    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0) {
        perror("Could not generate IP-address");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("Could not connect to server");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (send(sock, "Hello Server", strlen("Hello Server"), 0) < 0) {
        perror("Could not send message");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char buffer[1024] = {0};

    if (recv(sock, buffer, 1023, 0) < 0) {
        perror("Could not receive message from server");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    close(sock);

    return 0;
}

server.c:
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (server_fd == -1) {
        perror("Could not create socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in address;
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(address);

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(8080);

    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address)) < 0) {
        perror("Could not bind to host address");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (listen(server_fd, 1) < 0) {
        perror("Could not start listening");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int client_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, &addrlen);
    if (client_socket < 0) {
        perror("Could not accept client");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    if (recv(client_socket, buffer, 1023, 0) < 0) {
        perror("Could not receive message");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Received: %s\n", buffer);

    if (send(client_socket, "Hello World", strlen("Hello World"), 0) < 0) {
        perror("Could not send message");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    shutdown(client_socket, SHUT_RDWR); // wait for message to be received
    close(server_fd);

    return 0;
}

The server successfully receives the client’s message and prints:
Received: Hello Server

before exiting correctly.
However, the client freezes on the recv call after sending the message, even though the server sends a response. This issue seems to occur only on macOS—it works fine on other systems.
Is this behavior caused by a bug in my code or a quirk of macOS networking?
Edit
I used Wireshark to debug the network traffic and confirmed that the message is being sent and received as expected ("Hello Server" and "Hello World" are both sent and acknowledged). Below is the Wireshark trace for reference:


Unrelated bug: buffer (in both programs) isn't guaranteed to be NUL-terminated (except that you happen to send short messages that never fill it), so the following printf %s is UB.

Unrelated bug: send and recv aren't guaranteed to receive the whole "message". (They don't even have a concept of message.) The sender needs to let the receiver know when the message is complete, and the receiver needs to keep reading until the message is complete.

^^^ Which is often done by prepending the payload length (typically in big-endian format) at the start of the message ^^^

But what if you don't know the size in advance, you might ask. HTTP solves this by using a series of length-prefixed "chunks". A chunk with a size of zero indicates the end of the message. /// The alternative to prefixing the message with the length is to use a sentinel value. This sequence marks the end of the message. But you have to make sure the sentinel value can't be found in the message. This can done by disallowing it, or by escaping/encoding it.

I tried it on the latest MacOS, it works as expected for me.

@Viliam Holly, Did you check the server's exit code?

You don't print out confirmation that the server's send() worked.

@ikegami yes I did. The exit code is 0.

@JonathanLeffler, I do not need to print any confirmation, as I check the error code.

You do need to print a confirmation because you simply exit() if the send() fails and exit after doing silent operations if it succeeds.  Or you need to use perror() before calling exit().  But it would be simpler to print a message.  You do say "exits correctly" but that's vague — if you mean "exits with status 0 (success)", say so.  It would be correct to exit with a non-zero status if something fails.  Plus, when debugging, make sure you check everything that returns a status, and print copious information.

Unrelated bug: int addrlen; (socklen_t *)&addrlen is an invalid typecast. socklen_t is unsigned and may be larger than int. addrlen needs to be declared as socklen_t to begin with.

Possibly related bug: you should close() the client_socket descriptor before exiting. That lets the socket API know you are done with the socket and it can flush any unsent data.

@Barmar on which macOS version and model did you test it?

MacBook M1, running Sequoia 15.1.1.

@RemyLebeau I don't think there's any buffering in the socket API, it's not like stdio. And all file descriptors are automatically closed when a process exits. This will flush any kernel buffers.

@Barmar send() just copies data into a kernel buffer and then exits. The data is transmitted in the background. You have to make sure you give the kernel a chance to send that buffer and not abort it.

@RemyLebeau Once it returns, it guarantees to transmit it eventually, unless there's a network error. You don't have to do anything to flush it. Just like write().

@RemyLebeau Contrast that with stdio. fwrite() writes to a user-mode buffer, which may not be flushed if the process crashes.
